# How to embed a literal json within a YAML using jsonnet?

Tags: yaml, jsonnet

Here's what I'm trying to achieve using jsonnet:

```
version: "v1"
data:
  j.json: |-
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
```

Here's my failed attempt:

```
local j = {
  foo: "bar"
};

local wrapper = {
  version: "v1",
  data: {
    'j.json': |||
      j
    |||
  }
};

std.manifestYamlDoc(wrapper)
```

In my attempt I'm getting the following result:

```
"data":
  "j.json": |
    j
"version": "v1"
```

How can achieve a desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things there:

- the multiline string you build with the `|||` expression is a literal, would need `%<blah>` format operator as any other string
- looks like you want `std.manifestJson()` there
- I'd rather take advantage of JSON being YAML and use jsonnet output, fwiw more legible:

> foo.jsonnet:

```
local j = {
  foo: "bar"
};

local wrapper = {
  version: "v1",
  data: {
    'j.json': std.manifestJson(j)
  }
};

wrapper
```

> jsonnet output:

```
$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet
{
   "data": {
      "j.json": "{\n    \"foo\": \"bar\"\n}"
   },
   "version": "v1"
}
```

> verifying `j.json` field with `jq`

```
$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet | jq -r '.data["j.json"]' | jq
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```